# alter button properties in NSMutable array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

How do I alter the properties of a button (at an index) in a NSMutable Array?

here's my code:

```
                [btnRange addObject:btn12Out];
                [btnRange addObject:btn13Out];
                [btnRange addObject:btn14Out];
                [btnRange addObject:btn17Out];
                [btnRange addObject:btn18Out];
                [btnRange addObject:btn19Out];
                //start ordering   

                for (NSInteger i=0; i <= 5; i++) {
                    nxt = btnRange[arc4random_uniform([btnRange count])];
                    btnOrder[i] = nxt;                    
                    [btnRange removeObject:nxt];
                }


                //skipping down


    if ([status isEqualToString:@"Computer"]) {
        switch (level) {
            case 1:
                //here's where I want to edit the properties 
                //of a buttonn in the array (at a certain index)
                nxt = btnOrder[current];
                UIButton *newbutton = nxt;
                [newbutton setBackgroundImage:@"buttonmem3" forstate:UIControlStateNormal];


                //Fin
```

But xcode likes to say there's no @interfae for "newbutton"

Can anyone help?

Comment: forState maybe? capital S...

Comment: Also use [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonmem3"] not just string literal..

Comment: Thankyou Petro, it was the reference to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correction**:

`UIButton` method `setBackgroundImage:forState:` accepts `UIImage` as parameter and not `NSString`. Change the line as below.

```
[newbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonmem3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Assuming you have "buttonmem3.png" added in your app bundle.

Comment: FIXED! I thought it was bad referencing to the array but apparently not, thanks for that!